# Resharper: Cannot resolve symbol 'Eval' in VS2010 SP1

Tags: c#, asp.net, resharper, visual-studio-2010

I just installed SP1 for VS2010, and since then I get error messages from Resharper for stuff that used to work and be ok for Resharper (5.1) before.

The error messages are "Cannot resolve symbol 'Eval'" and some other methods other than Eval.

How do I solve this?
Is there a fix?
Is there some resharper cache that I must delete/clear?

(The code compiles and runs as usual)

Comment: Is your code compiling correctly?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I would try deleting the `_ReSharper.{SolutionName}` directory completely if clear cache fails.

You might want to close VS2010 before you do that.

EDIT: Try this only if @Andrew Finnell solution doesn't work.

Comment: I have my caches stored in the system temp folder. Start->Run "%TEMP%" without quotes. I deleted all of the ReSharper folders there, even those unrelated to the solution having the issue. All of a sudden though ReSharper does seem to be using MUCH more memory for this solution. It was usually just over 100MB, but I have seen it hovering around 350+. Deleting these folders did not resolve the problem for me BTW.

Comment: @bdwakefield If you have enabled the "Solution-widde analysis, ReSharper is probably re-indexing your solution. It takes a few minutes.

Comment: @Julien I do have solution wide analysis enabled. This situation was occurring for about a week. I haven't looked in the past few days but it seems to be down more around 130MB for that solution.

Comment: We don't use Solution-wide analysis even though I think it could be a helpful tool. It straight cripples our machines here. Recently we upgraded to R#6 and I am still seeing this issue at times. It also appears to be an issue for others as well. http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5310364;jsessionid=D8EA40A750BD586C4225759BC3123757

Answer (score 26):

Try:

```
Resharper Menu -> Options -> General -> Clear Cache button
```

Comment: An observation:  This did not **APPEAR** to work--but after closing and reopening VS the problem was gone.  Note that it had almost done Julien Berube's solution anyway, all that was left was a log.

Comment: If you don't want to restart VS, you can open the command window (Ctrl  + W, A), run ReSharper_Suspend, then run ReSharper_Resume.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in spades in my multi-project VS solution.  Tried Julien + Andrew's solutions and they did not resolve the issue.  But everything *compiled* just fine and worked as normal -- it was simply the "Errors in Solution" that kept showing the errors (which also showed up when you looked at the code in the right-hand-ReSharper-margin).

It turns out I had inadvertently deleted the web.config file in one of the solution's web projects during some version control operations.  Who knew that thing was important?

I restored the web.config file, cleared the cache and deleted the R# cache directories and then rebuilt all of the projects individually and the issues went away.

Phew!

Answer (score 0):

The solutions of @Andrew Finnell and @Julien Bérubé, alone and combined, did not fix my problem of "Cannot resolve symbol".

The comment of @bdwakefield pointing to [here](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5310302#5310302) finally shed light on my problem.

It turns out that my "not resolved symbol" contains a web reference, and ReSharper gets lost there somehow.

By the link above it is possible to see that this is also an issue for many people, but JetBrains guys were not able to reproduce the error until now (see [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-273951)).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with one of my projects.  I reported the issue to JetBrains and they requested a VS solution which has the problem.

So, I decided to spend a few hours trying to narrow down the problem as much as possible. I found out that the issue is related to a tool I use which strips out information from .DLLs.

If I don’t strip the .DLLs, Resharper works fine without showing any “cannot resolve symbol” errors.  However, If I do strip the .dll, then ReSharper starts to show these “cannot resolve symbol” errors.  In both cases, Visual Studio compiles the program and the program runs fine.

I am working with JetBrains to get the issue resolved.

In the mean time, I am able to workaround the problem by using versions of my .DLLs which do not have any information stripped out of them.