# Cannot resolve symbol issue with resharper but code compiles

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper-6.0

I know this has been asked before, but there was no solution to the problem, and it was last year, so I thought maybe someone has found something to solve this by now.
I am using VS2010 with SP1. before installing the SP1 there was no problem. if I uninstal re# it works fine. I have an ASP.Net website and some other projects. The classes from the other projects are not recognized, resharper suggests using the other project, so I do so, it puts it up at the usings, then the using also gets a "cannot resolve symbol". 
I have tried the suggestions they gave in 2011 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539131/resharper-cannot-resolve-symbol-eval-in-vs2010-sp1) but nothing.
if I delete the _Resharper. and restart vs, it will work for 5 seconds, then all red again...

hope someone found a solution to this since then...thanks

Edit: I have noticed it does this with Web Services

Comment: [Resharper “can not resolve symbol” even when project builds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713167/resharper-can-not-resolve-symbol-even-when-project-builds)

Answer (score 17):

Although this question is rather old it happended to me today. I solved it by going to menu `Tools -> Options -> Resharper`

Click on `Options` and press `Clear Caches` button followed by `Save`.

Then just click on the `Suspend Now` followed by `Resume Now` button to restart Resharper and your code should be ok again.

EDIT: happened to me again. Clearing caches helped. The only thing changed is that "Clear caches" is hidden under **General** tab in resharper options.

Comment: I cannot test it anymore since I have changed computers since then and not working on the project where this happened anymore...but waiting for people with the same issue to confirm the solution.

Comment: R# 8.2: I can confirm that this is the fix that I was looking for. Nice job, guys! Thanks.

Comment: This works for me, but when I restart Studio I have the same problem again. Is there a permanent solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with one of my projects.  I reported the issue to JetBrains and they requested a VS solution which has the problem.

So, I decided to spend a few hours trying to narrow down the problem as much as possible. I found out that the issue is related to a tool I use which strips out information from .DLLs.

If I don’t strip the .DLLs, Resharper works fine without showing any “cannot resolve symbol” errors.  However, If I do strip the .dll, then ReSharper starts to show these “cannot resolve symbol” errors.  In both cases, Visual Studio compiles the program and the program runs fine.

I am working with JetBrains to get the issue resolved.

In the mean time, I am able to workaround the problem by using versions of my .DLLs which do not have any information stripped out of them.

Answer (score 0):

1. in visual studio, Tools -> Options -> Resharper, Press Suspend Now
2. delete the folder _ReSharper.*
3. Tools -> Options -> Resharper, Press Resume Now