# Cannot resolve symbol 'ViewBag'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, resharper

I'm using VS2010 SP1, MVC3 and ReSharper 6.1.

In one of my projects I have following issue().

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'ViewBag'
```

I have this only in my Controllers.

[image]

In Views  it works fine.

[image]

I have check [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539131/resharper-cannot-resolve-symbol-eval-in-vs2010-sp1) and try suggested solution but it didn't work.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: Is your controller class deriving from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`?

Comment: @Ethan Brown. No it is deriving from my `BaseController` class. And `BaseController` is deriving from `Csla.Web.Mvc.Controller`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that your Controller is derived as

public class YourController : **Controller**

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have a right MVC configuration.
Ensure you have right config value with this tool http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/01/13/mvc-3-project-upgrade-tool.aspx