# "Cannot resolve symbol" error in VS with SMO

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2, resharper, smo

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll
Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum.dll
Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll
```

i have referenced all the above assemblies in my C# project but when i type

```
   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup bkpDatabase = new Backup();
```

i get an this error "**canot resolve symbol Backup**"  even when i have below using statements

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
```

Comment: Googling "Visual Studio cannot resolve symbol" suggests that this error is coming from ReSharper, not from VS itself, e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539131/resharper-cannot-resolve-symbol-eval-in-vs2010-sp1). I've added the reharper tag so hopefully you get a better response now.

Comment: i had not referenced Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended in my project in addition to the assemblies mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had not referenced Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended in my project in addition to the assemblies mentioned above.